# Docker deployment works with MacOs but not with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laravel, docker, npm, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerise my laravel app: https://github.com/xoco70/kendozone/tree/docker-local

My dev env is working, now I am working on a deployable app in local environment.

In MacOs, Everything is ok.

I build it with:

```
docker build . -f app.dockerfile.local -t kendozone:local-1.0.0
```

And run it with

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-local.yml up --force-recreate
```

The problem is with `npm run dev` with is a `webpack` build command

It will just compile Sass, combine Js and CSS, and copy it to `/var/www/public folder`

But when I run my app in ubuntu, I can access login page but it seems to load without any css / js.

With MacOs, I can see them with no problem....

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:

  # The Application
  app:
    image: kendozone:local-1.0.0
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - codevolume:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "DB_USERNAME=homestead"
      - "DB_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"
    depends_on:
      - database

  # The Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - codevolume:/var/www
    ports:
      - 8090:80
    depends_on:
      - app

  # The Database
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
  codevolume:
```

Any Idea ???

Comment: are you using some mounts (volumes) in docker-compose.yml that contain these files?

Comment: mmm. yes, I guess, I addded my docker compose to question so you can confirm it

Comment: when you mount volume to container, the content of volume "replace" the files in that container. So if your volume is blank, you are just mounting blank folder and overwriting your files. Can you try `docker-compoe down` then delete the volumes so they are recreated again when you do next time `up`... also go inside the docker container and verify the volumes are blank so you wont lose any data....

Comment: I will try it at home :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is to make node available in your docker base image, and then actually run npm install and npm run production to build a production ready image of your application.